# SVN: Error setting property 'log': Could not execute PROPPATCH

Tags: svn

I am trying to do a simple commit in SVN (I'm using Cornerstone on a Mac). The commit fails with the following error:

Description : An error occurred while contacting the repository. [...]
Error : V4CommunicationError [...]
Description : At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged
Status : 175008 [...]
Description : Error setting property 'log': 
Could not execute PROPPATCH.
Status : 175002 [...]

I have tried reinstalling Cornerstone, and I have tried checking out the repository to another directory and committing from there.

Comment: Maybe this could help you? In my case, the reason was `svn:global-ignores`
https://stackoverflow.com/a/63477624/4575793

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found [another site](http://www.nodans.com/index.cfm/2009/9/29/How-to-resolve-svn-Error-setting-property-log) that mentioned something about "single line comments." My commit message didn't have multiple lines, but it did have smart quotes that I copied and pasted from our bug tracking system. Here is the offending phrase:

“Ingredients”

When I took away the smart quotes, I was able to commit.

Answer (score 23):

I had this issue in Versions, it seems that this issue is caused by using "rich text" in the commit message. Hope this makes the issue and solution a bit clearer.

Comment: This answer solved my problem. I copied some text from a excel document to my commit message. Commit is successful after removing those text.

Comment: This solved my issue as well pasting an issue number from JIRA

Answer (score 2):

In my case there were mergeinfo records referencing a directory that was long since deleted on the SVN.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue using English and Russian in one line in commit comments. After deleting and retyping the message only in one language (Russian) commit succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

This was caused due to rich text usage including hyphens and new line characters in the commit message window of Cornerstone. Here's a quick solution -

1. Right click on the repository < Open using Terminal
2. Check in your code via terminal. Here's an example -

`svn ci -m $'This is the first line\nThis is the second line'`

Answer (score 1):

The same issue with me. I copied comment text from MS Words and paste into comment textbox.

**Solution:** I removed text and write it again. so don't copy and paste comment from any edition

Answer (score 0):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN Change the SVN Interface Client as something like SVNKit version. You are done, you can put any no. of lines as you want.

[image: image here]

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, while merging you have to use "prefer repository" option in case of "merge-info" file conflict.