# Tortoise SVN Error on commit: 'Invalid PROPPATCH property'

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I'm using tortoise svn 1.6.16 on a Windows 7 machine, and getting an error on commit, as below:

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow):  
Error: At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged  
Error: Invalid PROPPATCH property
```

[A previous question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086570/svn-error-setting-property-log-could-not-execute-proppatch) indicated that this was due to quotes in the commit message, but that is not my issue.

I've tried re-installing svn, and have also tried making my changes a second time on a clean checkout of my project. The error still persists though.

Can anyone recommend a way to access the invalid PROPPATCH property and fix it? Or is there a known workaround to get me over this hump? Any info much appreciated.

Comment: Resolved this by using the svn protocol when working with local repositories, and, ultimately, moving away from svn and using git!

Answer (score 14):

To elaborate on @Sergey Bodrov's answer, it may be that your repository is using Git, and not supporting the "ignore" property. This was what fixed it for me: Right-click on the working copy root folder, select Tortoise SVN > Properties, remove the "svn:ignore" property and then commit works fine.

Comment: Thanks. this really helped me

Comment: To add to this answer: it seems that GitHub now supports `svn:ignore` through it's SVN bridge. I, however, received this error after "recursively" ignoring some file in TortoiseSVN, which uses the *client* property `svn:global-ignores`. ("The big difference here is that the global ignore list is a client property." https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html). I don't know why TortoiseSVN tries to commit this to the server, but it seems to try to do just that. Solution: as above with `svn:global-ignores`.

Comment: @bers "svn:global-ignores" is a versioned SVN property introduced in 1.8, "global-ignores" is the client-only pendent: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.special.ignore.html

Comment: @ThorstenSchöning: thanks, that explains why TortoiseSVN (tries to) commit this to the SVN server, which failed with GitHub in May. I have not tested it since, it might just work now.

Comment: @bers It doesn't, had the same problem today an it'd documented: "GitHub doesn't currently support svn:externals, svn:global-ignores, or any properties not listed above, including custom properties." https://help.github.com/articles/subversion-properties-supported-by-github/

Comment: Worked for me! Except mine was svn:global-ignore

Answer (score 6):

Your SVN server not support some properties for directories (ignored files list, for example).

- exclude (uncheck) directory from commit list and don't set directory properties
- or use another SVN server

Answer (score 2):

To elaborate even more on all the answers (that led me to the solution, thanks a lot), in my case I did not know witch property was set, so I used the command line to list the properties:

```
svn proplist * --recursive
```

So, I saw the name of the property and removed it:

```
svn propdel svn:global-ignores --recursive
```

Answer (score 0):

### Solving the issue:

- Find and browse to the folder that causes the error and check his properties (or these of the superfolders) - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32691479/4575793)

[image: Navigate to the Properties of the respective folder]

- Remove the svn:global-ignores (you can edit the "normal" ignores to still match your needs)

[image: resolving the problem by removing svn:global-ignores]

---

### Reproducing the error can be done like this:

- Try to (globally/recursively) add an item to the git ignore list as shown in the figure

[image: Adding to git ignore with TortoiseSVN]

- Click on <kbd>OK</kbd> and have a server that does not support this duch as [github.com](http://github.com)
- you get the error described by the OP