# TortoiseSVN ignore list is not working

Tags: svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

Although I have told TortoiseSVN to ignore *.avi and *.exe files, when I commit, TortoiseSVN still wants to commit those files.

[image]

Comment: Are those files already versioned? Because SVN ignore patterns will only ignore _unversioned_ files.

Comment: @Wrikken: No, this is a brand new repository. Is there an alternative to TortoiseSVN, because it seems incredibly buggy.

Comment: @user2327109 0_0 what?

Comment: @user2327109 Don't blame the tool if you just don't know how to use it.

Comment: Unless you set that property recursively, or those extensions are in your global ignore list, you aren't actually ignoring those extensions. Note that those files are not in the top-level directory you're committing, but subdirectories.

Comment: for me, ignoring only top directory worked!

Answer (score 27):

Recently I ran into same problem and I found an article on svn enhancements where someone mentioned that error message (file cannot be added to ignore list) is not user friendly as it does not give you more information on why the file could not be added to the ignore list.

The file I was trying to add to the ignore list was not stored under a versioned folder. And interestingly, SVN is expecting the file-to-be-ignored stored under a versioned folder.

I simply ignored the entire folder (bin & obj in my case) and Tortoise SVN happily accepted it.

Comment: This got me thinking. I the error by trying to add the file to the ignore list. After reading your comment I realized the containing folder hadn't been added (unversioned). Once I added the folder then TortoiseSvn let me add the file to the ignore list.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another answer.

Open the svn properties for the parent folder and it should have an svn:ignore property listed. Edit that by adding your directory to ignore.

But watch out for the PROPPATCH error [SVN: Error setting property 'log': Could not execute PROPPATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086570/svn-error-setting-property-log-could-not-execute-proppatch)

Answer (score 0):

You've either already versioned these files (in which case setting up an ignore pattern would be relatively pointless) or you've setup the ignore pattern in the wrong place. An ignore pattern is set up at the folder level and applies to non-versioned files and folders immediately under it. You can have an ignore pattern recursively applied to a group of folders so that certain extensions like `*.avi` and `*.exe` are ignored throughout the folder tree.

What you need to do is SVN-Revert any SVN-Added and/or SVN-Delete any committed AVI and EXE files, then apply your ignore pattern to your group of folders. Fortunately, TortoiseSVN allows you to `Delete and add to ignore list`, however, this only applies to the containing folder so if you want to do this recursively, you will have to edit the SVN Properties of the top-level folder.

Hope this helps.