# Removing single svn:external giving PROPPATCH error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-externals

We have a thridparty repository where we have externalized all the third party libraries. From there, we pull these libraries to the server code repository.

Earlier, we had two versions of junit (4.10 and 4.11) which were externalized. I am working on a defect in which I want to unify the use of JUnit 4.11. So I removed the svn:external for JUnit 4.10

When I am commiting the updated svn:externals using `TortoiseSVN`, I am getting the following error.

```
Error: Commit failed (details follow): 
Error: At least one property change failed; repository is unchanged 
Error: Error setting property 'externals': 
Error: Could not execute PROPPATCH.
```

I have gone through a similar question : [SVN: Error setting property 'log': Could not execute PROPPATCH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11086570/svn-error-setting-property-log-could-not-execute-proppatch) but this din't really help.

Please let me know your inputs.

Comment: Can you find out what was in the server error log?

Comment: Ok. Spot on.. I got an error in server logs "Cannot accept non-LF line endings in 'svn:externals' property".
@BenReser : Please add your comment as an answer, so that I can offer you the bounty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting the following error in server logs :

```
Cannot accept non-LF line endings in 'svn:externals' property
```

It seems that since I am using TortoiseSVN for loading the properties through a text file, there were some invalid characters in that file.

To resolve the issue, I removed the single junit 4.10 SVN:externals entry from SVN properties displayed for the directory, instead of removing the line from text file and loading the file again.

Answer (score 1):

So first of all checking the error log on the server is likely to tell you exactly what the problem is.  Based on your followup saying that you were receiving an error about non-LF line endings in the `svn:externals` property it's clear that the problem you are having is related to the requirement that all svn properties (those whose name starts with `svn:` be written in UTF-8 and lines be terminated with line feeds not carriage returns.  Since 1.6.0 in reaction to [Subversion issue 1796](http://tortoisesvn.net/community.html) this has been enforced on the server (the issue talks about `svn:log` but it applies to all properties starting with `svn:`). TortoiseSVN should be translating the line endings for you.  Since it is not I would recommend that you first make sure you have the newest version of TortoiseSVN and if you do then [report the bug to the users list for TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/community.html).

Comment: Same error after deciding to use a file for ignores. I'm on Windows, so file had CRLF. No access to server log using beanstalkapp.com. Updated to the latest version of TortoiseSVN, used Tortoise context menu Properties, Edit the svn:ignore row, Load to read my file, apply recursively. I get PROPPATCH error on commit. I then edited my file in Notepad++, ensure the Encoding menu is in UTF8, but more importantly, used the Edit menu, EOL Conversion, and picked UNIX/OSX Format. Click "Show All Characters" button in the toolbar, all line endings clearly show as LF. The commit now works!

Answer (score -1):

Go to Window -> Preferences -> Team -> SVN
Change the SVN Interface Client as something like SVNKit version.
You are done, you can put any no. of lines as you want.
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEeyd.jpg)
Thanks